# Notification position in 'Asp.net. Boilerplate'

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

Is there any possibility to change the window display location of soft notification abp.notify.warn?

Can we adjust the display window x y in `abp.notify.warn()` soft notification?

```js
abp.notify.warn(app.localize('EmployeeNotFound'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's toastr plugin. The implementation is done in abp.toastr.js.
Write the code below to configure position.

```
toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-top-right';
```

[image]

Comment: pardon me, where should I write this line? I mean which file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to implement custom CSS to achieve your goals targeting the `sweet-alert` css class.

You should take a look at the [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) documentation. Every abp popup uses this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The notification use toastr plugin to display message, you can refer to toastr demo [here](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html). And change something that you want in abp.toastr.js file

Answer (score 0):

You can modify in this file in the latest version of ABP:

**abp.notify.js**

Answer (score 0):

Actually the abp.notify.warn allows passing an `options` parameter. So that you can easily specify the exact X,Y position for the notification box.

This is the method signature:

```
NotifyService.warn(message: string, title?: string, options?: any): void
```

Accordingly, you can adjust the display window x,y Like this:

```js
abp.notify.warn(app.localize('EmployeeNotFound'), '', {
      "position": "55,150"
    });
```

There is a set of predefined positions if you like to use too:

> 'top', 'top-start', 'top-end', 'center', 'center-start', 'center-end',
> 'bottom', 'bottom-start', or 'bottom-end'